# Auto resize images in container Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm actually coding a web page in HTML5/CSS3/JS. It's composed with images that are clickable with different effects (modals, hover, etc ..). I'd like to positions elements with precision in a container (in order to make the composition easyly usable) and not directly in the page. An arrow have to be centered in the box and different buttons have to be placed in different areas. (cf. image)

1. What is the best way to do that ? With relative or absolute positionning ? Will it be absolute comparatively to the container ?
2. How to make the content of the container responsive (in order to keep the proportions of the composition). Can I use Boostrap containers for that ?

This is a screenshot of what i what to do (an image for buttons and an image for the arrow) :
[image: Screenshot of the composition]

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Make a container that is the height and width of the arrow image and set it to `position:relative;` then use `position:absolute;` with top/bottom and left/right positioning for the other images within the container.

Comment: position:relative; in order to place the arrow  or for the container ? :)

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment here's one way you could do it(with the first two dots positioned):

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}
img.point {
  position:absolute;
}
  img.point.one {
    bottom:103px;
    left:57px;
  }
  img.point.two {
    bottom:21px;
    left:57px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- <img class="final" src="https://s31.postimg.org/70gvh473f/final.jpg" /> -->
  <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/g5p8azai3/arrow.jpg" />
  <img class="point one" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point two" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point three" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point four" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point five" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point six" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point seven" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point eight" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point nine" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point ten" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point eleven" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
  <img class="point twelve" src="https://s31.postimg.org/rjbrm6l0r/dot.jpg" />
</div>
```

As far as responsiveness goes, you would just have to change the size of the dot images as well as the bottom/left values at each breakpoint. The easiest way to position the dots is to have the final image positioned within the container and then using the inspector to position the dots over the final image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="position:absolute;left:-50;top:-5;font-size:1px;width:250;height:10px;"> your code </span>
```

1. position: Absolute should be used more often. It is actually kind of counter intuitive of absolute and relative if you look up on [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
   position: Absolute helps you define the precise position related to the previous element, which is what you will be using for arrangement of lots elements .
2. Use variables instead of fix numbers to keep the elements spacing in a constant ratio.